# Pandas not dropping columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Hi I've tried to drop columns based on a boolean array but for some odd reason pandas does not seem to be dropping the columns at all.

The boolean array is  and (376,). It only contains True and False values.

```
for x in range(0,len(analysis)-1): 
    if analysis[x] == False:
        col =  dtest.columns[x]
        dtest.drop(dtest.columns[x],1)
```

This is my code for dropping the columns, essentially the length of the analysis array is the number of columns there is in dtest.

dtest is (4209, 376) & pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

I have tried debugging, it does detect the Falses in the analysis and also is able to print out the col variable accurately but it just wont drop the columns for some reason.

Would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you don't need `loop`:

```
dtest = dtest.loc[:, analysis]
```

Demo:

```
In [320]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 10), columns=list(range(1, 11)))

In [321]: df
Out[321]:
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10
0  0.332792  0.927047  0.899874  0.294391  0.762800  0.861521  0.988783  0.475127  0.033096  0.980141
1  0.447273  0.268828  0.951633  0.947425  0.020006  0.808608  0.607091  0.712309  0.383256  0.248582
2  0.169946  0.951702  0.671014  0.514326  0.607129  0.227021  0.831474  0.696117  0.799418  0.224851
3  0.724165  0.748455  0.452430  0.941572  0.873344  0.877872  0.925788  0.183115  0.113217  0.072717
4  0.303488  0.426459  0.750076  0.225662  0.298983  0.729585  0.692489  0.934778  0.124634  0.274208

In [322]: analysis = np.random.choice([True, False], 10)

In [323]: analysis
Out[323]: array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [324]: df = df.loc[:, analysis]

In [325]: df
Out[325]:
         1         2         3         5         6         7         10
0  0.332792  0.927047  0.899874  0.762800  0.861521  0.988783  0.980141
1  0.447273  0.268828  0.951633  0.020006  0.808608  0.607091  0.248582
2  0.169946  0.951702  0.671014  0.607129  0.227021  0.831474  0.224851
3  0.724165  0.748455  0.452430  0.873344  0.877872  0.925788  0.072717
4  0.303488  0.426459  0.750076  0.298983  0.729585  0.692489  0.274208
```

Comment: @kimpster, glad it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

You need assign output back:

```
cols = []
for x in range(0,len(analysis)): 
    if analysis[x] == False:
        col =  dtest.columns[x]
        cols.append(col)

dtest = dtest.drop(cols,1)
print (dtest)
   0  2
0  1  3
```

but better is select only columns by `True` mask like in another answer.